# Usar str_replace substitur tag <br> por <p>

Tags: php

Pessoal preciso substituir as tags `br` por `p` no meu construtor xml e para isso estou utilizando o método `str_replace` mas ele não está fazendo essa substituição.

Segue o código:

```
$i=1;
foreach ($xml->channel->item as $item){
   if($i <= 30){        
       if(substr($item->link, 0, 23) == 'https://www.site.com.br'){
    $imagem = '';
    if($item->images->image != ''){
        $imagem = '<figure> <img src="'.str_replace(' ','',str_replace('alt=','',str_replace('"','',str_replace('src=','',str_replace('/>','',$item->images->image))))).'"/>  </figure>';
    }
    $newItem = $newXML->addChild('item');
    $newItem->addChild('title', $item->title);
    $newItem->addChild('link', $item->link);
    $newItem->addChild('guid', $item->guid);
    $newItem->addChild('pubDate', $item->pubDate);
    $newItem->addChild('content', '
    <![CDATA[

        <head>
          <meta charset="utf-8">
          <link rel="canonical" href="'. $item->link .'">
        </head>
        <body>
          <article>
            <header>
            <h1>'.$item->title.'</h1>
            '.str_replace('<h2></h2>','','<h2>'.$item->summary.'</h2>').'
            '.$imagem.'
                            </header>

            <!-- Article body goes here -->

            '.str_replace('<br><br>','</p><p>',$item->content).'
            <figure class="op-tracker">
                <iframe src="https://www.site.com.br?nota=' . $item->link .'" hidden></iframe>
            </figure>


            <footer>

            </footer>
          </article>
        </body>
    </html>
    ]]> ');
$i +=1;
}}  
}
print($newXML->asXML('teste.xml'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Observe que para você conseguir fazer esse tipo de substituição, o código retornado em `$item->content`por exemplo, precisa ser exatamente `<br><br>` sem nenhum caracter entre eles. Se for `<br/>`, não vai funcionar ou se for apenas um `<br>` também não.

Compartilhe um trecho do código do seu xml (se for possível). Assim chegaremos a uma solução mais adequada.